# ReactJS routing issue after deployment in production

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have some routing issues for my ReactJS application post deploying into a subdirectory in production domain.

I am placing the build files into directory `www.xyz.com/folder1/appfolder/` on my website and my homepage attribute in package.json is set to the same path. I have also tried to use manifest.json "start_url": "./dashboard" And my application file has route defined as below

```
<Route exact path="/" component={DashboardPage} />
```

Expected: When I run on localhost everything works fine as in the default page is the dashboard page when I visit localhost. But in production when I visit

```
www.xyz.com/folder1/appfolder/
```

i expect the dashboard page to load up but it doesn't load but a blank page comes up with all left nav, header, footer with no content. Once I click on Dashboard link in side nav then the page loads up but with this URL

```
www.xyz.com/appfolder/ (missing folder1 in path)
```

If I take this below path and visit directly then its broken as well

```
www.xyz.com/appfolder/
```

Only when I visit below and then click on side navbar dashboard link then it redirects to just app folder and the page loads up.

```
www.xyz.com/folder1/appfolder/
```

Kindly suggest as something really basic is missing due to which I am facing this problem. its a bad user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [basename](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) prop in your `BrowserRouter`

```
<BrowserRouter basename='folder1'>
...routes...
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I have tried this. Still not working.
While there is some improvement where I now get the folders in the URL.
Ex:

Comment: I have tried this. Still not working.
While there is some improvement where I now get the folders in the URL.
Ex:
www.xyz.com/folder1/appfolder/ (Clicking on sidebar links takes us to)
www.xyz.com/folder1/navpage1 etcc. instead of previous  www.xyz.com/navpage1

There are 2 issues:
www.xyz.com/folder1/appfolder/  doesnt take me to the ('/' redirect component which in this case is set to 'DashboardPage' is still not displaying.
Second issue is routing path still has issues missing appfolder in the path
www.xyz.com/folder1/navpage1  instead of expected domain/folder1/appfolder/navpage1

Comment: If your whole app is in `folder1/appfolder/` then use this as your basename...... if you `/appfolder/` is just your landing page and you have other pages like `/folder1/secondpage` that you want to route, you can redirect your root to `appfolder` like `<Route exact path="/" ><Redirect to="/appfolder" /> </Route>`

Comment: Thank you I just made that fix and works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hashrouter instead of browser router.

So in your app.js (if this is where you have your routes defined)

Change the import like this

FROM

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
...
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardPage} />
    ....
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

TO

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
...
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardPage} />
    ....
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: This is not recommended if you plan on having your site indexed by search engines 

As mentioned; 
- [Here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/javascript/javascript-seo-basics#5), 

- [Here](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/definitive-list-reasons-google-isnt-indexing-site/118245/)

- and [here](https://seranking.com/blog/single-page-application-seo/)