# react routes not redirecting to pages on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

So I have a deployed a react app to heroku. In local host the routes work fine. The default being homepage and the 'portal/' going to the login/sign up page which works normal with http://localhost:3000/portal.

On heroku however it just redirects/stays on the homepage. Even if I do a route that doesnt exist?
something like https://my-hero-app.com/random-route

I am using a github-heroku pipeline so its always up to date

let me know if you need any more information! Thanks!

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from './pages/homepage/Homepage'
import Portal from './pages/portal/Portal'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">


      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />}></Route>
          <Route path="/portal" element={<Portal />}></Route>

        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be a lot of things, did you build your app to production? did you serve it using nodejs or express? is your Procfile properly configured?

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. yeah react frontend with node/express backend. Although the backend is only for serving data from the database and the front end still renders fine without it as I built it first without the backend and its been fine on heroku until i added a second page. Also no procfile as its done entirely though github

Comment: It's not API server that I am saying. Serve your built react app. Here check this out https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-aedc28b218ae

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. My deployment is a react application heroko done through a github pipeline

Comment: Also you still need procfile so that heroku knows where how to start your app

Comment: I have already deployed my react app to heroku, that isnt the issue. its routing to other pages that isnt working

Comment: Checkout the link i sent.

Comment: I see, then I have no idea what is the issue with your app. Mine worked perfectly

Comment: you have react routing working on a deployed heroku app?

Comment: yes, Its working fine even when changing pages. do you have your app uploaded in github? perhaps I could check?

Comment: can you show your routing section in what i assume is your App.js or otherwise?

Comment: it's basically the same as yours. Im not sure the problem with your app is in routing exactly.

Comment: do you have a procfile in your react app?

Comment: yes, like i said it is the entry point of your heroku so it's kinda a must to have it if you deploy there.

Answer (score 0):

if you used node.js you will need to change the port. Try this.

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

This should normally fix the issue. It basically means whatever is in the environment variable PORT, or 3000 if there's nothing there.

Comment: my backend is on a different deployment and works fine. my homepage on the front end in heroku deploys as it should I just cant access the second page through routing (despite routing working fine on localhost)

Comment: Sorry but it is very strange. I am not sure that I will be able to help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The home page "/" matches all paths. If you want to handle 404 pages you will want to create another route with path "*". This explains why random paths display the home page

As for why '/portal' refuses to render are you serving your app in a different directory perhaps on deploy? If so you'll want to set basename

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar">
    <Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
    <Link to="/tomorrow"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/tomorrow">
</BrowserRouter>
```

[ReactJS routing issue after deployment in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650256/reactjs-routing-issue-after-deployment-in-production) may be a simliar situation to what you've described

Comment: its the exact same folder structure and everything as my local, if thats what you mean?

Comment: only simmilar thing i can find is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772411/react-routing-works-in-local-machine-but-not-heroku but this is for server side so honestly probs not helpful

Comment: what do you mean another path with "*"?